# How to ship python application through docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerhub

I just now started using docker.

I made a python application using python 2.7. Python code files are in my system and in bitbucket repository. I am able to run that file in my local system through eclipse.

Now,  how I can run that files in my docker and distribute the python application to other users(don't want to show code).

Can help me explaining the steps in simple language

Answer (score 3):

Docker is in no way a mean to hide your code

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run your code in the container, you will have to copy over your code into the container. If you don't want to expose the source code, compile python and distribute binaries. Use Cython to compile python to C code, then distribute your app as python binary libraries (pyd) instead.

Here is an example:
http://blog.biicode.com/bii-internals-compiling-your-python-application-with-cython/

---

Do the following 3 steps on your host to copy the code to docker container:

1.Get short container id :

```
docker ps
```

2.Get full container id

```
docker inspect -f '{{.Id}}' SHORT_CONTAINER_ID
```

3.copy file :

```
sudo cp path-to-file-on-host /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/FULL_CONTAINER_ID/PATH-TO-NEW-FILE-IN-CONTAINER
```

---

The way to run the code in container should be the same as you run on your host. Maybe there are some configurations required for the ports and ip.

Comment: How to copy code in container, code is in local system windows directory. Then how to run it in docker. Can you help in this.